# How to import templates with Structr behind a proxy

Tags: structr

I am following the Structr tutorial (https://support.structr.com/article/232) on a Linux machine. It fails when trying to import the jumbotron template from the Internet. I think this is because my machine is behind a proxy, so Structr and/or Java need to be configured to use that proxy.

Structr does not seem to have a proxy setting in the configuration file, and it does not seem to take the env variable http_proxy into account.

Could you please tell me what is the best way to configure the proxy settings for Structr?
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. I'll forward it to the team, we'll investigate and report back. If you like, you can create a new issue in the project's GitHub repo: https://github.com/structr/structr/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 2.1 (to be released around GraphConnect San Francisco 2016), Structr will support outbound HTTP proxy connections. There will be a global, a personal (bound to your user ID) and a use-case specific configuration (for instance a different proxy for each external site you configure in the Crawler).